# Does std::ofstream guarantee the old open file will be closed if opening new one?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, file-handling, iostream

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    auto fout = std::ofstream("/tmp/a.txt");
    fout.open("/tmp/b.txt"); // Will "/tmp/a.txt" be closed?
    fout.open("/tmp/c.txt"); // Will "/tmp/b.txt" be closed?
}
```

**Does** `std::ofstream` **guarantee the old open file will be closed if opening new one?**

Comment: I don't see any explicit specification of the behavior.  `ofstream::open` essentially passes the `open` call onto its raw device buffer.  The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) for that is not specific about what happens if a _different_ file is already open, nor what should happen if you open a file and the open fails.  However, you should at least expect that _if_ a new file is opened on that object, the old one _will_ be closed, because the device buffer is responsible for managing a single resource and will not leak resources.

Comment: Just wanted to put this hear since you deleted your other Q.  In C++20, comparisons got a major update and one of those was that `operator ==` should work both forwards and backwards.  That means you don't need to write two overloads anymore when you want to have the LHS and RHS be different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second and subsequent calls will fail.

> **[filebuf.members]**
> `basic_filebuf* open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode);`
> 2 *Effects:* If `is_open() != false`, returns a null pointer. Otherwise...

> **[ofstream.members]**
> `void open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);`
> 3 *Effects:* Calls `rdbuf()->open(s, mode | ios_base::out)`. If that function does not return a null pointer calls `clear()`, otherwise calls `setstate(failbit)`